# Mocking HttpSession using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, session, junit, mockito

I need to test the following controller method:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/addLocation")
public String addLocation(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    String location = (String) request.getParameter("plz_ort");
    String radius = (String) request.getParameter("umkreis");

    ((ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("queryTopics")).clone();        

    ...
}
```

Therefor I wrote this test class using Mockito and JUnit

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

public class MyControllerTest {


    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    MockHttpSession session;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MyController)
                .build();

    }

    @Test
    public void addLocation_StatusOK() throws Exception {
        session.setAttribute("queryTopics", new ArrayList<String>(0));

        this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/addLocation")
                        .param("plz_ort", "PLZ ORT")
                        .param("umkreis", "5"))
                .andExpect(
                        status().isOk());

    }

}
```

As you can see I need to mock the session when running this test.
When I debug through the code and stop at the line `session.setAttribute("queryTopics", new ArrayList<String>(0));` the session object is `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession@5583d693` (containing a attributes hash map `{queryTopics=[]}`), so I think that's fine.
However the session object of my next breakpoint in line `((ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("queryTopics")).clone();` is `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession@7545a27f`.

At least it's the correct type (`MockHttpSession`) but it's got a different ID so it's actually a whole new object and thus doesn't contain the session attributes from the test.

Could you please help me out on this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mock MVC will create a spring mock request and a spring mock session and then invoke your controller method. In order to set some state in the session before the controller method is called, you need to [configure the mock request](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#sessionAttr-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) using the builder:

```
public class MyControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MyController)
                .build();

    }

    @Test
    public void addLocation_StatusOK() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/addLocation")
                        .param("plz_ort", "PLZ ORT")
                        .param("umkreis", "5")
                        .sessionAttr("queryTopics", new ArrayList<String>(0))
                .andExpect(
                        status().isOk());
    }
}
```